# Rails redirect_to subdomain of account using simple syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a Rails noob and I'm sure this is fairly straightforward but I'm not sure how to do it, so I'm going to ask for help.

Here's my situation. I have a Rails 3 app. The app follows the subdomain as account key pattern like Basecamp does. What I would like to do is redirect to the subdomain using this syntax (let's say the current account is `@account`).

`redirect_to @account`

Currently, (as it should), this redirects to `/accounts/(@account.id)`. What I would like to do is make it redirect to `(@account.subdomain).myapp.com`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
redirect_to "http://#{@account.subdomain}.myapp.com/"
```